# Custom method submit in form component container

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a component Angular containing my header and footer of all of my form like this :

```
 <div class="layout vertical">
  <header class="layout horizontal center">
    <h2> {{enterData?.title}} </h2>   
  </header>

  <!-- Form -->
  <form [formGroup]="formName" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()"
        class="layout vertical">
   <ng-content></ng-content>

  </form>

  <footer class="layout space-between horizontal">    
    <div class="buttons-footer-layout">
      <!-- buttons -->
      <paper-button class="btn-cancel-alt" type="reset" (click)="close()" id="cancelInc">{{labels.BTN_ANNULER}}
      </paper-button>
      <paper-button class="btn-action"
                    [disabled]="!formName.valid || formName.pristine
                    (click)="submit()"
                    id="saveInc">
        {{labels.BTN_CREER}}
      </paper-button>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

and the TS file :

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'enter-data-container',
      templateUrl: './enter-data-container.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./enter-data-container.component.scss']
    })
    export class EnterDataContainerComponent {
  @Input() enterData: EnterData<any>;
  @Input() formName: FormGroup;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,
                  private  location: Location) {
      }
    /**
       * On submit du form
       */
      submit() {
     // Send Data to service

    }
    /**
       * on click cancel
       */
      close(): void {    
          this.location.back();    
      }
    }
```

In many form I have in my app, the submit is always the same, but sometimes, it's slightly different.
So I want to give the possibility to override the submit function when it's needed.
How can I achieve that with Angular 2/4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use $event.preventDefault()

```
<paper-button class="btn-cancel-alt" type="reset" (click)="close(); $event.preventDefault()" id="cancelInc">{{labels.BTN_ANNULER}}
      </paper-button>
```

Comment: this is not my problem, I want to override submit function in component if needed.

Comment: I think you are using multiple forms in same html page with one component using the same submit button and want to override the submit button. Is that right

Comment: yes it's right, I found a solution with dependency Injection.
I call submit function of a SubmitService provided in app.module.ts
and when I need to override SubmitService I do in the parent Component :
provide: [{provide: SubmitService, useClass: MyNewSubmitService}]